# How to convert .Doc to Tiff/Jpeg programmatically using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, doc

I need to find a way of converting Word Doc files to Jpeg of Tiff files using C#/.NET. I cannot use any virtual printing drivers such as Microsoft Office Document Imaging. I can only use C# and/or C++ Libraries. Are there any free methods or APIs to accomplish this?

Comment: Graphics.CopyFromScreen() is free.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this does not allow for conversion of word docs consisting of multiple pages.
Is there any other solution that automates the process of converting multiple multi-page word docs to image files?

Comment: Couldn't you use Word automation to scroll one page at a time and Graphics.CopyFromScreen() each page? You problably would have to make sure that the page fits the screen by setting the apropiate zoom to the document. I know this is an ugly hack but it's just to comment on the multi-page issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to something first - such as PDF. Then you can run ghostscript to convert it to your jpg/tiff files.

You can write a program in c# that..

- opens word, prints all docs in a folder to PDF driver and closes,
- and then converts all PDFs in folder to tiff/jpeg using ghostscript,
- and then deletes all intermediate PDF Docs.

I know you say you can't use a virtual printing driver but I'm pretty sure you have to.